# More than 10 000 entries in sql server audit log

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an audit which tracks all queries for a certain database. Because there are a lot of queries which are run by sql server itself the log is quite big. When I view the audit log  (right click on name of audit - View Audit Logs) I only ever see 10,000 records.

[image: view audit log]

The audit is configured like this:

[image: audit configuration]

Is there a way to view more than 10,000 records at once? I'd like to export all records to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> The number of rows that are displayed for audit logs can be configured
>   on the SQL Server Object Explorer/Commands page of the Tools/Options
>   dialog box.

Setting it to 0 returns all rows.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fn_xe_file_target_read_file TVF to query audit and other extended event file target data. Just specify the audit file path, including wildcards:

```
SELECT *
FROM (N'K:\SQL Server 2012\Data_DB*.sqlaudit',DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT);
```